# Magento2.2.0: Generate custom Order attribute to show in Checkout and whole Order Process

Tags: attributes, sales-order, magento2.2

I need to generate custom order attribute dynamically, I have gone through all the core module of magento 2 and try to understand the working of attributes for products and customers, but got no clue to generate attributes in the same manner as `products` and `customers` in `eav_attribute` table.

I got some articles on generating attributes for order but those are not satisfactory , as they are suggesting to add a custom column in `sales_order` table.

[Magento2 Adding Custom Order Attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107280/magento2-adding-custom-order-attribute)

What if I want to generate multiple order attributes?

Thanks.

Comment: what you are after is defined as extension attribute in magento2 laned

Comment: @AntonS, not understand what you want to say?